# Problems with Explorer and Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a responsive layout using Angular that figures the screen width in the Controller:

```
        $scope.getWidth = function() {
        return $(window).width();
    };

    $scope.$watch($scope.getWidth, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        var window_width = (newValue / 1000);
        var window_width = window_width * .96;
       $scope.window_width = window_width.toFixed(3);
        });


    window.onresize = function(){
        $scope.$apply();
    }
```

Uses a filter to round the number up to the nearest pixel:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
  .filter('decimal', function () {
   return function (input) {

  return Math.ceil(input);

 };
});
```

And outputs it like this:

```
<div style="width: {{(1000 * window_width) | decimal}}px;"></div>
```

It works fine on everything but Internet Explorer.  There are no errors, the style tag is just blank.  Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: What version(s) of IE?

Comment: I checked it on a few machines at Best Buy which I assume uses the most recent version

Comment: Could you put a plunker together to demo?

Comment: I'll try, in the meantime here's the live site: http://www.interweb.co

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/l52wHl  I'm on a Mac so I can't tell for sure but that shouldn't work with IE

Comment: The plunker link is broken.

Comment: Ugh plunker is completely down at the moment but I think you just take the 'edit' out of the url

Comment: You can read more about the issue hear. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2186

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer  :  http://plnkr.co/edit/Boy09W1QNkvJXGTU6P2j?p=preview